# Error: Page Not Found (404) Path: /login/authenticate

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I am trying to install basic spring security plugin 3.1.2 for Grails 3.
I created USer and ROle and I can see them created in the database using MySQL but I am getting

```
Error: Page Not Found (404)   Path: /login/authenticate
```

error. I am not sure why it's going to authenticate view as my 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/inputParam/news'
is this one it should go to news ..How to check if user successful logged in..
I tried creating login controller but it's not passing any params at the backend

Comment: it would be easier if you push project code (or just related part) to the repo and show us. I think issue may be related with mapping.

Comment: https://github.com/psnehal/gsesuite  this is the repository : So my main aim is display http://localhost:8080/inputParam/main   but restrict http://localhost:8080/inputParam/chipInput this link ..for that i added :grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
 [pattern: '/inputParam/main',  access: ['permitAll']],
 [pattern: '/inputParam/chipInput',  access: ['USER_ROLE']],